NextRouter was not mounted when use useRouter hook from next/router
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const Navbar2 = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
 return (
    <nav className={`fixed top-0 w-full px-10 bg-white p-4 transition-all duration-500  ${isVisible ? 'top-0' : 'top-[-160px]'}`}>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        {/* Brand Logo  */}
        <div className="w-[40%]">
          <Image src={logo} alt="Brand Logo" className="w-20" />
        </div>
        {/* menu item */}
        <div className="flex-1">
          {/* main menu */}
          <ul className="flex items-center justify-between mt-10">
            <li><Link href="/" className={router.pathname === '/' ? "text-[#7B003B]" : ''}>Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/" className={router.pathname === '/' ? "text-[#7B003B]" : ''}>About us</Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/" className={router.pathname === '/' ? "text-[#7B003B]" : ''}>Admission</Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/" className={router.pathname === '/' ? "text-[#7B003B]" : ''}>Safeguarding</Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/" className={router.pathname === '/' ? "text-[#7B003B]" : ''}>School life</Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/" className={router.pathname === '/' ? "text-[#7B003B]" : ''}>Sixth Form</Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/" className={router.pathname === '/' ? "text-[#7B003B]" : ''}>News</Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/" className={router.pathname === '/' ? "text-[#7B003B]" : ''}>Alumni</Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/" className={router.pathname === '/' ? "text-[#7B003B]" : ''}>Contact us</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Navbar2;

Thisi is the code snippet I want to show the active navlink but when I try to  use the
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

I got the error Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted
I expected that it would show the active link in my nav menu

Are you using useRouter outside a next application?

If you are using newer version of NextJS such as 13 or 14, useRouter is no longer available on next/router but rather from next/navigation.
Also, pathname doesn't exist on the router object anymore, there is a separate hook for that which is the usePathname hook.
As a side note, you should create a links array and map through it, that will make your code cleaner and avoid repetition.
See code block below.


import {
  useRouter,
  usePathname
} from "next/navigation";


export default function YourComponent() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return ( < div > Whatever... < /div>)
  }



